# How to extend lifetime of the local variable or what is right way to use references

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, move, object-lifetime

I was developing some class and bumped for this question.
Consider I have following class:

```
struct A
{
    int *p;
    A() 
    {
        p = new int(1); 
        cout << "ctor A" << endl; 
    }
    A(const A& o) 
    { 
        cout << "copy A" << endl;
        p = new int(*(o.p));
    }
    A(A&& o) 
    {
        cout << "move A" << endl;
        p = std::move(o.p);
        o.p = NULL;
    }
    A& operator=(const A& other)
    {       
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            delete p;
        }
        p = new int(*other.p);
        cout << "copy= A" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator=(A&& other)
    {       
        p = std::move(other.p);
        other.p = NULL;
        cout << "move= A" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        if(p!=NULL)
            delete p;
        p = NULL;
        cout << "dtor A" << endl;
    }
};
```

And following class which has `A` as a property:

```
class B {
public:
  B(){}
  A myList;
  const A& getList() { return myList; };
};
```

And this function which checks for some variable value and returns different objects in different cases:

```
B temp;
A foo(bool f)
{
    A a;
    *a.p = 125; 
    if (f)
        return a;
    else
    {
        return temp.getList();
    }
}
```

Now, I am want to use this function like this:

```
A list1 = foo(true);
if(list1.p != NULL)
    cout << (*list1.p) << endl;

cout << "------"<<endl;
A list2 = foo(false);
if (list2.p != NULL)
    cout << (*list2.p) << endl;
```

The purpose of this situation is:

Function `foo` should return (or move) without copying some local object with changes in `p` if argument is `true`, or should return property of global variable `temp` without calling copy constructors of `A` (i.e. return reference of `myList`) and also it should not grab `myList` from `B` (it should not destroy `myList` from `B`, so `std::move` can not be used) if argument is `false`.

My question is:

How should i change function `foo` to follow upper conditions? Current implementation of `foo` works right in `true` case and moving that local variable, but in case `false` it calls copy constructor for `list2`. Other idea was to somehow extend lifetime of local variable, but adding const reference did not work for me. Current output is:

```
ctor A
ctor A
move A
dtor A
125
------
ctor A
copy A
dtor A
1
dtor A
dtor A
dtor A
```

Comment: The problem is what you want to return from `foo` is something that might or might not own an `A`  and there is no such thing as an optionally-owning smart-pointer but you could probably make one.

Comment: @ChrisDrew so you think it is impossible to accomplish my conditions for `foo` with only C++'s references mechanics and move semantics?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, but someone cleverer than me might prove me wrong. I think you could accomplish what you want with a `std::shared_ptr` or your own wrapper that might or might not own an `A`.

Comment: And I am forced implement and use some custom structures for handling this situation?

Comment: @ChrisDrew anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think that you need to create a custom class for this, if you need the optimal solution. Here's a related question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597835/c-optimizing-out-destructor-call

Comment: Your copy-ssignment operator is not exception-sfe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change `B` to

```
class B {
public:
  B(){}
  std::shared_ptr<A> myList = std::make_shared<A>();
  const std::shared_ptr<A>& getList() const { return myList; };
};
```

then `foo` can be:

```
B b;
std::shared_ptr<A> foo(bool cond)
{
    if (cond) {
        auto a = std::make_shared<A>();
        *a->p = 125; 

        return a;
    } else {
        return b.getList();
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd9dfa257040eced)

Output is

```
ctor A
ctor A
125
------
1
dtor A
dtor A
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, works like a charm!

Comment: By the way, if someone know certainly whether it is possible to do it without smart pointers but with some move semantics and const referencing feel free to answer, I am interested in learning its mechanics deeper.

Comment: May I disturb you again? I read comments more precisely and now want to try change my definition of `foo`. Is it possible to do what I asked without pointers if `foo` would return const reference for the `A`? For example, I am not going to change `A` further, read-only access now is enough for me.

Comment: @EgorSchavelev: No, it's not safe to return by reference any newly created object.  If the object is automatic, it will be destroyed before the return, and the caller will be left with a useless (dangling) reference.  If the object is dynamic or added to some global collection, the reference will be valid, but the object will also leak.

Comment: @BenVoigt But what about prolonging lifetime of an object? As I said, now I can afford getting const reference. Something like here: https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/extending-the-life-of-a-temp-variable-in-c/

Comment: @Egor: Lifetime extension doesn't apply here.  The object is not a temporary, it's a scoped local.  And return-by-reference never causes lifetime extension.  You have a totally different scenario than the one shown on that blog.

Comment: @EgorSchavelev: You can do it without a smart pointer. You can store a flag in A, whether it owns `p` or not. This way, you can create an `A`, which can store a pointer to `b.p`, but doesn't own it. But you must be careful, you must not delete `b.p` afterwards, because `A` will refer to the same memory area.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is probably to use `std::shared_ptr` as in Jarod42's answer. But if you want to avoid smart pointers, or if you can't change `B` you can probably create your own wrapper class that might or might not own an `A`. `std::optional` might be quite convenient for this:

```
class AHolder {
  private:
    std::optional<A> aValue;
    const A& aRef;
  public:
    AHolder(const A& a) : aRef(a) {}
    AHolder(A&& a) : aValue(std::move(a)), aRef(aValue.value()) {}
    const A* operator->() const { return &aRef; }
};
```

The class contains an `optional` to own the `A` if required and you can use move-semantics to move it in. The class also contains a reference (or pointer) that either references the contained value or references another object.

You can return this from `foo`:

```
AHolder foo(bool f)
{
    A a;
    *a.p = 125; 
    if (f)
        return a;
    else
    {
        return temp.getList();
    }
}
```

And the caller can access the contained reference:

```
  auto list1 = foo(true);
  if(list1->p != nullptr)
    cout << (*list1->p) << endl;

  cout << "------"<<endl;
  auto list2 = foo(false);
  if (list2->p != nullptr)
    cout << *list2->p << endl;
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RabORzfiHRZdi14n).

If you don't have access to `std::optional` there is `boost::optional` or you could use `std::unique_ptr` at the cost of a dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Your function *foo* returns an instance of *A*, not a reference (nor a pointer), so you can`t get access to *B.myList* content without copying or moving.

In order to have this access you should either use smart pointers (like Jarod42 wrote) or just simple pointers like this:

```
B temp;
A* foo(bool f)
{
    if (f)
    {
        A* ptr = new A;
        *ptr->p = 125;
        return ptr;
    }    
    else
    {
        return &temp.getList();
    }
}
```

However this particular code will not work coz *.getList()* returns const reference but *foo* returns non-const pointer (this could but should not be dirty hacked with const_cast<>).

Generally you need to choose what exactly the *foo* function should return:

- new instance of *A* class with specific data
- access to existing instance

If you have to make this decision on runtime (for example by your bool parameter) then the pointers (simple or smart - whatever) are the only option (also remember to delete manually allocated memory).

Comment: This is a sure way to introduce a memory leak, unless all callers know that calling foo(true) returns a freshly allocated A and foo(false) returns a pointer to a statically owned A.

Comment: It is. Yet having a function that returns references (no meter in what way) and instances depending on input is already a possible memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was interested to do it without managing memory and preferably using move semantics and some features of C++11/14.

Comment: Than you have to work with references. In such case you need to either return const reference for both local *A* and *myList* or const_cast one of them if you are sure in does not crush the program. The most suitable solution depends on what are you going to do with returned values - just observe or write somewhere or else...

Comment: @Gleb: Your comment appears to advocate returning a dangling reference :(